# Why does this ternary operator for toggling animation in jQuery not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a `div#words_3` to slowly toggle its width when I click `.read_more`. It works for expanding its width first, but it doesn't toggle back. Can someone help me figure out, why that is?

```js
$('.read_more').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#words_3').animate(
  {
    width: (words_3.width == '85%' ? '42%' : '85%')
  },1500);
});
```

```css
#words_3 {
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="read_more">Button</button>
<p id="words_3">Something</p>
```

Comment: I'm guessing because jQuery's `width()` always returns an integer, not percentage.

Comment: Try using `.css('width')` instead of `.width()`

Comment: What's `words_3`, what's `.width`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with CSS and a class that you toggle to change the width.

I added `transition: width 1.5s;` to the style of the progress bar so it will animate the `width` for 1.5 seconds, and when you add the `short` class to it the width will be animated.

In the JS part, I only toggle the `short` class of the progressbar element to change its width from the CSS:

```js
$('.read_more').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Here I remove the `width` inline style so it won't override the CSS style
  $('#words_3').css('width', '').toggleClass('short');
});

$('.random').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#words_3').css('width', Math.floor(Math.random() * (101)) + '%');
});
```

```css
#words_3 {
  color: #fff;
  background: blue;
  transition: width 1.5s;
  width: 85%;
}
#words_3.short {
  width: 42%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="read_more">Button</button>
<button class="random">Random</button>
<p id="words_3">Something</p>
```

I also added a `random` button that when clicked, it change the width to a random number to demonstrate how you can use it with any width value.